# SMD Code search

Tags: identification, markings

I search an IC, SMD Code SOT23-6 "5091U" [image]

Comment: Can you add a photo that shows more of the surrounding components, preferably the entire board?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not confident with this being an answer, but I feel like it's more than a comment. It's a bit of a guess, but at least it gives you something to measure and thus verify or falsify.

It *could* be a step-down DCDC converter from Nisshinbo, such as a [RP509N001D-TR-FE](https://www.nisshinbo-microdevices.co.jp/en/pdf/datasheet/rp509-ea.pdf).

- It's SOT-23-6
- The marking style of line and text is similar
- The part-number includes part of your identified markings on it

[image]

I asked about a larger view of the board to hopefully spot an inductor and more capacitors somewhere. Again, this is a guesstimate and not confirmation.